# Waiting for enough suitable peers before syncing

Tags: ethereum, web3js, go-ethereum

I am running an ethereum node on Windows 11. I am using Geth for my execution client along with Prysm for my consensus client. They have been syncing for the past two days but no data is being written to my hard drive by Geth and no progress is being made towards a working ethereum node.

I installed Geth through the download page.
I installed Prysm with this command in an administrative Git Bash in the Prysm directory;

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prysmaticlabs/prysm/master/prysm.bat --output prysm.bat
```

I run both Geth and Prysm in separate administrative command prompts.

This is the command I use to start Geth;

```
geth --datadir D:\ethereum --authrpc.addr localhost --authrpc.port 8551 --authrpc.vhosts localhost --authrpc.jwtsecret jwt.hex
```

This is the command I use to start Prysm;

```
prysm.bat beacon-chain --execution-endpoint=http://localhost:8551 --jwt-secret=jwt.hex --suggested-fee-recipient=0x01234567722E6b0000012BFEBf6177F1D2e9758D9
```

I always start Prysm after starting Geth.

My Geth terminal repeats the message "Beacon client online, but never received consensus updates. Please ensure your client is operational to follow the chain"

My Prysm terminal commonly displays messages such as

> ←[90m[2023-01-17 20:30:44]←[0m ←[32m INFO←[0m←[36m initial-sync:←[0m Waiting for enough suitable peers before syncing ←[32mrequired←[0m=3 ←[32msuitable←[0m=0

Below are screenshots of my Geth and Prysm terminals.

[Geth terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Isk5D.png)
[Prysm terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8D12.png)

Why is Geth not writing any data? My friend who has a working node says it should write about 800gb.

Answer (score 2):

If your node does not find any peers in the peer-to-peer network, it cannot download any data and sync.

This is usually a sign of a local network issue. Make sure your node has a public IP address or has properly exposed ports to Internet. Preferably any computer in Internet should be able to connect to your computer running Prysm.

[See the documentation here](https://docs.prylabs.network/docs/prysm-usage/p2p-host-ip).